# Custom validator - start with issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rev" runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txt" Display="Dynamic"                    
                    Text="invalid"
                    ValidationExpression="[AB]\w*" />
```

The above custom validator should force user to enter values that start with **AB** and **CD** but don't know how to add that second **CD** parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the regex

```
(AB|CD)\w*
```

The `|` represents an `OR`

[Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

Also, have a look at the MSDN guide on Regex's.

I do not think that you want to use the `[]` judging from your question. Try `()` instead.

Here is the MSDN documentation I mentioned above

[Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlanMoore the OP probably hasnt come back onto SO since posting

Comment: According to his [profile page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/480231/1110) he was still active as of a few minutes ago.  And I assumed he would be notified of the new activity because he's the OP, but it seems I have to send it to his address with @1110